# How to inject a service Bean in a groovy script?

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I have a spring boot application and a separate groovy script that runs within the app and I need to inject a CustomService into the groovy script.

How do i achieve that? i tried reading the documentation but it's not so clear

i tried adding the @Autowired annotatino but it gives me an error and I dont think that's how it should be done.

Comment: What does even means to inject bean into GROOVY ? do you mean how to inject into IOC container of your spring boot project ?

Answer (score 0):

- How to **inject** **dependency** into IOC container of spring boot project with Groovy

Let imagine here is you `CustomService`

```html
public class CustomService {

    private final String smtPerhaps;
   
    ...
}
```

Then inject the bean as

```html
beans {
    yourDesiredBeanNameInContainer(CustomService) {
        smtPerhaps = 'stackOverFlow'
    }
}
```

Its quit the same as the Java base dependency injection

```html
@Configuration
public class JavaBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomService yourDesiredBeanNameInContainer() {
        return new CustomService("stackOverFlow");
    }
}
```

Find out more in [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4).